# Cannot return a value from a method

Tags: java

Having a hard time returning hours entered by the users with this following code... I believe that the total number of hours entered by the user from Sunday-Saturday is successfully passed to the 1st constructor but I cannot return the number of hours.

```
public static TimeCard processTimeCard(String data)
{
   String[] split = data.split(",");
   String employee = split[0];
   String project = split[1];
   double rate = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);

   double hours = 0.0;

   String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                      "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                      "Friday", "Saturday"};

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Get number of hours for each day of the week
   for (int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
   {
       System.out.println("How many hours on " + days[index] + ".");
       hours += Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
   }

   TimeCard arrow = new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours);

   return arrow;

   }

}

class TimeCard
{
// Instance Variables
private String employeeName;
private String project;
private double rate;
private double hours;

//Class Variables
private static int numCards = 0;
private static final double OT_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;
private static final int OT_LIMIT = 40;


/**
* Constructor 1
*/
public TimeCard(String employee, String project, double rate, double hours)
{
    this.employeeName = employee;
    this.project = project;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    numCards++;
}

/**
 * Constructor 2
*/
public TimeCard(String employee, String project)
{
    rate = 0;
    hours = 0.0;
    numCards++;
}

/**
 * Constructor 3
*/
public TimeCard(String employee)
{
    project = "none";
    rate = 0;
    hours = 0.0;
    numCards++;
}

   /**
 * Accessors
*/
    public String getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

error I get is

```
   error: incompatible types
   return this.hours;

   required: String
   found; double
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? `incompatible types`, `required: String`, `found: double`. Those cannot be any clearer. What is the type of `hours`? What is the return type of the method?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your getter method:

```
public String getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

It is expecting to return a `String` but `hours` is type `double`. So update your method to:

```
public double getHours() { /* Your code */ }
```

But if your really need your method to return a `String`, then convert `hours` to a `String` first before returning:

```
return String.valueOf(this.hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the `double` to `String`

```
public String getHours()
{
    return String.valueOf(this.hours);
}
```

Or change the function return type to `double`

```
public double getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
public String getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

to

```
public double getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the accessor:

```
public double getHours() {
    return this.hours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dude come whats this. try to debug properly before posting question here.

```
  public String getHours()
   {
    return this.hours;
   }
```